# glibc_2.27 not found electron

Tags: linux, npm, raspberry-pi, electron, glibc

I'm trying to execute an Electron app on my raspberry but i got an error.

i have tried to change the version of electron to the 3.0.13 (i had search on internet and said that this was the solution, but didnt work)

```
/home/pi/GENIUS/ElectronNFC/nfc-pcsc/node_modules/electron/dist/electron: 
/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by 
/home/pi/GENIUS/ElectronNFC/nfc-pcsc/node_modules/electron/dist/electron)
```

When im trying to run my program it has to start it, but instead im getting this error

Comment: The version of GLIBC used to compile that App is either too new or too old for the Raspberry PI. I bet it is probably too new. Did you ever upgraded the Raspberry PI? Check this link: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/updating.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a version of the Electron application built for your GNU/Linux distribution.  But if you cannot get that, something built for an older version of another distribution (such as Debian jessie or Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7) might help.  Unfortunately, you do not say which distribution and version you are using, so it is difficult to make proper recommendations.

Another alternative is building Electron yourself from source, on your system, but given the size of Electron's dependencies, that can be quite an effort.